# trying to php lint check with maven antrun plugin

Tags: php, maven, lint, maven-antrun-plugin

Looking for some help, trying to find a way to make Maven antrun plugin interate over ALL files in my php module, executing php -l (lint check) on them all.

If I use failonerror property set to true, it will fail as soon as it hits one bad file. If I use the resultproperty with a fileset (current implementation) then it parses all files, but the return code is from the first execution of php lint, so it only fails if the first file is bad.

```
<apply executable="php" failonerror="false" resultproperty="myresult">
  <arg value="-l" />
  <fileset dir="${basedir}">
    <include name="**/*.php" />
  </fileset>
</apply>
```

I've tried to use a different method of calling php -l, using find (from http://kamisama.me/2012/07/02/faster-php-lint/ ), but it still seems to quit on the first broken file.

```
<target name="lint" description="Perform syntax check of sourcecode files">
  <exec executable="bash" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="-c" />
    <arg value="find -L ${basedir}/src -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 4 php -l" />
  </exec>
</target>
```

Could use some help with antrun syntax or a method which will check all files, but exit at the end IF one *or more* files fail the lint check.

I've also considered githooks, but am not in charge of that system.

Any tips appreciated!

Comment: Taken a look at [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) ?

Comment: I'll give it a try. Any chance of an example? (The docs all seem java-centric)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using AntRun plugin in the end, moved away from 'resultproperty' to using 'errorproperty' with append. If there are any errors, it will continue checking all files, appending further errors until all the files have been checked.

After a few other checks, it then reaches a report phase where it will spit out all the errors found so far, and if the 'errorproperty' was not empty, it will fail the build. (This puts the errors right at the end of the output, and saves having to scroll a long way up through the jenkins / maven logs to find the lint errors)

Hope this helps someone!

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>lint-php</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target name="lint-php" unless="skipExecution">

                            <echo>Execution of the php linter</echo>
                            <echo></echo>
                            <apply executable="php" failonerror="false" errorproperty="lint-errors" append="true">
                                <arg value="-l" />
                                <fileset dir="${basedir}">
                                    <include name="**/*.php" />
                                </fileset>
                            </apply>

                        </target>
                        <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
...
                <execution>
                    <id>report-status</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target name="exit" unless="skipExecution">
                            <echo message="PHP lint check warnings:" />
                            <echoproperties regex="lint-errors" format="xml"/>
                            <echo message="----------" />
                            <fail message="PHP linter found linting errors">
                                <condition>
                                    <not>
                                        <equals arg1="${lint-errors}" arg2="" />
                                    </not>
                                </condition>
                            </fail>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```